# Подскажите, что учить, чтобы развиваться в Highload

Tags: highload

Решил, что мне интереснее всего в программировании будет работать с высоконагруженными системами. Не знаю, почему так решил - ведь не углублялся в это никогда. Знаю, что нужны: C/С++, Erlang, PHP. Подскажите, какие технологии нужно изучить, какие языки, чтобы мало-мальски начать в этом разбираться. Комментарии наподобие "не лезь, если не понимаешь" прошу оставить при себе. Лезу, как раз, чтобы начать понимать. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: >Решил, что мне интереснее всего в программировании будет работать с высоконагруженными системами.

я бы тоже хотел уметь **сам** решать, что мне будет интересно

Comment: Могу подсказать только одно. Просто берите задачу у решайте. А потом через опыть сами поймете что вам нужно. И читайте литературу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*0.Креатив и  готовность помучиться*

---

1. Система фортенд/бэкэнд - надо хорошо знать и понимать, как правильно расставить цепочку серверов. Так-же важно не забывать и полностью использовать все возможности локальной сети.
2. Чёткое понимание того, для чего нужен nginx и apache.
3. Чёткое понимания linux, а также готовность делать изменения в ядре (вспоминаю доклады яндекса...)
4. C/C++. Быстрые языки - если надо что-то на скорость, то используем их. К тому же именно они являются 'главными' в linux
5. Java/Python/Ruby и может быть Go. Выбирайте любой и используйте как основной северный язык. Хотя можно использовать и perl. Но по мои меркам он слишком стар.
6. SQL и noSQL базы данных. Тут хозяин-барин и должен выбирать сам.
7. Lua - очень-очень не помешает. Хотя он и не обязателен. Просто как вариант

Насчёт php решать вам самим. Тут беда даже не в скорости, а в его костылях. Ну смотрите:

1. Мир нашёл ещё одну уязвимость в php
2. Патча ждать долго, т.к. девелоперы php не оперативны
3. Но вам надо срочно исправить эту дыру
4. Вы **второпях** делаете собственный патч
5. Тот вдруг замедляет работу php
6. Или хуже того, после патча вообще что то перестало работать

Хотя ИМХО это только мое мнение. Поэтому я держусь от php подальше. А как поступите вы - вам решать.

**UPDATE1** Чуть не забыл про ajax и comet, которые сокращают кол-во траффика

Answer (score 1):

Это так странно, но в своем вопросе вы сами на него же и ответили...ну по краней мере частично:

**ASK:**

```
 Подскажите, какие технологии нужно изучить, какие языки, чтобы мало-мальски начать в этом разбираться.
```

**QUEST:**

```
 Знаю, что нужны: C/С++, Erlang, PHP.
```

Боюсь, что "благодаря" такой каше в изложенных вами мыслях, можно посчитать вопрос бессмысленным...

---

**P.S**

Я ни в коем случае не намекаю на "не твое - не лезь!". Всякий путь начинается с первого шага...и вот вы пытаетесь сделать первый шаг, но уже сразу немного оступаетесь, изложив свои мысли по поводу HighLoad не совсем корректно. Тем более я уверен, что при искреннем желании постичь высокие нагрузки, вы бы сами все отыскали все необходимое в сети...

Comment: http://www.highload.ru - отсюда узнал про то,какие языки используются. Знакомился и с С++,и с Эрлангом,и с РНР. И тут стопор - что вообще необходимо знать? Понятное дело, что работать нужно будет с серверами и тд, но конкретных названий технологий я не знал. Вы говорите - гугл, но не лучше ли спросить программистов,которые, если ответят по существу, то видимо работают в этой сфере на реальных проектах. Да, видимо надо было поставить вопрос иначе: какие,ПОМИМО НАЗВАННЫХ, языки и технологии необходимо знать, чтобы развиваться в направлении highload?   А ваш комментарий полезного ничего не несет

Comment: Архитектуру серверов (SMP, ccNuma), системы виртуализации, High Availability и High Performance кластеры, быстрый интерконнект (например infiniband), свитчинг-роутинг, устройства хранения (**большие** дисковые массивы типа EMC, Hitachi HDS и т.п. и Oracle Exadata), ускорители ввода-вывода и т.п. железо и т.д. и т.п.

--

Просто без приличного представления о технике (железе и firmware) в этой области спроектировать разумный софт не получится.

Comment: Окей, буду учить и стараться) Спасиб)